# This add on could not be installed because it is not verified error

Tags: firefox, 22.04, email, thunderbird, add-on

I cannot install the [Send Later](https://addons.thunderbird.net/fr/thunderbird/addon/send-later-3/) add-on which schedules an email to be sent later.

When clicking on the `send_later-9.0.11-tb.xpi` file, I receive the following error in Firefox:

`This add on could not be installed because it is not verified.`

I tried opening `about:config` page, setting `xpinstall.signatures.required` and `extensions.langpacks.signatures.required` to `false` and restarting Firefox, according to this [link](https://support.mozilla.org/fr/kb/signature-modules-complementaires-firefox?as=u&utm_source=inproduct#w_comment-faire-pour-utiliser-un-module-non-signe-utilisation-avancee), but it didn't work out.

Any suggestions on how to install this add-on?

(Ubuntu 22.04 LTS)

Answer (score 0):

Solution: go to `Tools > Add-ons and themes` and add the `Send Later` add-on directly to Thunderbird.